# Android - Logcat sem funcionar/em branco

Tags: android, android-studio

Meu logcat não está funcionando. Quando inicio o emulador e clico na aba do Logcat, nenhuma informação aparece só fica em branco, como se não estivesse conectado a nenhum dispositivo.

A tela fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

O problema pode ser resolvido de forma simples, basta reiniciar o serviço do logcat.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Encontrei a solução com base nessa resposta do SOen:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26565593/6736591